# Nvidia Quadro K2200 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Possible?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, graphics

So I'm a n00bie to Ubuntu/Linux. I've been trying to get a Quadro K2200 to work with the most recent update to Ubuntu, due to my Windows installation causing me more grief than necessary. I've spent the past two weeks looking at tutorials, resources, etc. Is it even possible to get the K2200 to work with this version of Ubuntu? If so, does anybody know any tips or tricks to possibly get it to work from a clean installation? I know support is supposed to be rough around the edges for the Quadros but I've heard other people have gotten different cards in that series to work, so I'm not sure what's going on. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This card is supported. If you have trouble booting with it, use `nomodeset` boot option, then install Nvidia drivers by

```
sudo apt install nvidia-367
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, add the Graphics Drivers PPA and then install 375 instead. This version is the only one currently recommended by Nvidia for K2200M

Comment: Bot 367 and 375 are recommended. It does not matter much.

Comment: Adding PPA and installing 375 worked to get the card up and running, but it's now locked to 4:3, highest resolution available is 1152x864. Have a 1080p monitor, and it's clipping about 20px on the top as well. Is this a driver mismatch or something? Any thoughts on a possible fix? Really appreciate the assistance thus far!

Comment: You may need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS to get the nvidia module working.

Comment: I've disabled secure boot and it's still locking it to 1152x864. Tried both drivers to see if either one would work, still no joy. Any other thoughts? Again, really appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes happens when using VGA cable, that there is no screen information provided and Linux is blocking any modes of resolution and screen refreshing.
If monitor is using VGA, then try to swap out with a DVI or HDMI cable (using native ports, i.e. without an adapter)